# Dagger 2 with WorkManager without Dagger-Android

Tags: android, dagger, android-workmanager

I am trying to use Dagger2 standard library with `WorkManager`. But in the examples on the internet they are using with dagger-android which I do not want. So, can you please suggest some solutions for this, so that I can use `Dagger2`, NOT `dagger-android` with `WorkManager`.

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Comment: You can use [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager) to inject a worker.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can see that Hilt is the recommended option

Answer (score 1):

This example using `Kotlin`.

```
class YourWorker(ctx: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(ctx, params) {
   @Inject
   lateinit var yourModel: YourModel

   init {
      getServiceComponent().inject(this) // or you create your component here and inject worker to it
   }
}
```

```
@ServiceScope
@Component(
        dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class}
)
public interface ServiceComponent {
    void inject(YourWorker worker);
}
```

Comment: Is this the example using Hilt?

Comment: It's dagger2 not hilt

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a worker using Hilt.

Use `@WorkerInject` in the constructor of your worker. You must also annotate the `Context` and `WorkerParameters` dependencies with `@Assisted`:

```
class ExampleWorker @WorkerInject constructor(
  @Assisted appContext: Context,
  @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
  workerDependency: WorkerDependency
) : Worker(appContext, workerParams) { ... }
```

And setup WorkManager configuration in your `Application` class:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class ExampleApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

  @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

  override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
      Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager